# How many processes does this program make?

Tags: operating-system, system-calls

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* arg[])
{
    fork();
    if (fork())
    {
        fork();
    }
    else
    {
        char* argv[2] = { "/bin/ls", NULL };
        execv(argv[0], argv);
    }
    fork();
}
```

In my opinion,
First fork() leads to 2 processes
and
inside if(),
fork() leads to 4 processes,
and since, child process returns 0
two parent processes goes inside the condition
and makes whole number of processes 6
and final fork() leads to 12 processes.
But chatgpt said it's 16 processes.
Why am I wrong? Is 16 answer for this question?

I'm studying OS, and there's a question.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

ChatGPT regularly makes the stuff up, you can never rely on the information provided by it. In this case, it just counted the number of `fork()` calls and assumed that each doubles the number of processes. It completely missed the fact, that not every `fork()` is called on every execution path.

The answer I've come up with is 10 - you have to remember, that `execv()` call never returns, so two child processes produced by `if(fork())` will never reach the final `fork()`. That's why the answer is less by 2 than the one you've come up with.